# Cannot access GeoServer on http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web

Tags: geoserver, jetty

I have a fresh installation of GeoServer 2.8.0 on Windows 7. I installed GeoSever several times before, and usually, I can access it after installation simply in the browser via `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web`. However, this time I only get an:

[image]

What could I possibly do?

This is what I get on manual startup:

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\bin>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre
6\bin\java.exe" -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\dat
a_dir" -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -Djet
ty.port=8080 -Djetty.logs="C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\logs" -jar "C:
\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\start.jar"
2015-11-03 11:43:24.475::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2015-11-03 11:43:24.638::WARN:  Deprecated configuration used for C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2/webapps
2015-11-03 11:43:24.676::INFO:  jetty-6.1.8
2015-11-03 11:43:24.924::WARN:  failed org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@27
391d{/geoserver,file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.6.2/webapps/geose
rver/}
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geoserver/GeoserverInitStartupListen
er : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoade
r.java:366)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoade
r.java:337)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.jav
a:1035)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfi
guration.java:629)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXml
Configuration.java:367)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfigu
ration.java:289)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfigur
ation.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlCo
nfiguration.java:180)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.jav
a:1217)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:
510)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448
)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHan
dlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:
130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
2015-11-03 11:43:24.958::WARN:  failed ContextHandlerCollection@116ab4e
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geoserver/GeoserverInitStartupListen
er : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoade
r.java:366)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoade
r.java:337)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.jav
a:1035)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfi
guration.java:629)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXml
Configuration.java:367)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfigu
ration.java:289)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfigur
ation.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlCo
nfiguration.java:180)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.jav
a:1217)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:
510)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448
)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHan
dlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:
130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
2015-11-03 11:43:24.04::INFO:  Opened C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\log
s\2015_11_03.request.log
2015-11-03 11:43:24.05::WARN:  failed HandlerCollection@1434234
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geoserver/GeoserverInitStartupListen
er : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoade
r.java:366)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoade
r.java:337)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.jav
a:1035)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfi
guration.java:629)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXml
Configuration.java:367)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfigu
ration.java:289)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfigur
ation.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlCo
nfiguration.java:180)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.jav
a:1217)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:
510)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448
)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHan
dlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:
130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
2015-11-03 11:43:24.047::WARN:  Error starting handlers
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geoserver/GeoserverInitStartupListen
er : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoade
r.java:366)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoade
r.java:337)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.jav
a:1035)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfi
guration.java:629)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXml
Configuration.java:367)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfigu
ration.java:289)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfigur
ation.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlCo
nfiguration.java:180)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.jav
a:1217)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:
510)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448
)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHan
dlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:
130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
39)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
2015-11-03 11:43:24.118::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: check the log files - most likely is some other program using port 8080

Comment: Have you started the Geoserver. If it is not installed as service, then it has to be started manually.

Comment: yes it is installed as a service and started

Comment: and the logfiles do not give any hint

Comment: I'm also having problems connecting to this, could it be because I have Java 8? The funny thing is, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: yes, try it with java 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need Java 7 to run this version of Geoserver. If you install it and reinstall Geoserver (pointing to the jre7) you should be fine.

I would also recommend to install the new version to a different directory. At the moment you seem to have it installed to "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.2\" (see log messages above). A clean reinstall would be better.

Comment: yes, the problem was I took JRE 6

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, and try several hours to uninstall and reinstall my geoserver. Later on I found this geoserver Web archive: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/war.html. I follow the instruction and everything works out. Good luck!!

Comment: Welcome. Be aware links can break with time. If it breaks your answer will not make sense anymore. Therefore, I suggest you to summarize the content of that link and edit in to make your answer self contained. Let the link be, so to give proper citation. Thanks.

Comment: First reply ever over here, thank you Andre and I will try to be more helpful next time.

Comment: No problem but you can still edit your answer to make a summary of what is available on that link. It is up to you. Thanks.