# Geoserver Admin not launching http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web

Tags: geoserver

This is similar to this post:

[Cannot access GeoServer on http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168831/cannot-access-geoserver-on-http-localhost8080-geoserver-web)

I'm getting error 404 not found for localhost:8080/geoserver/web

I downloaded GeoServer version 2.10.5 and pointed the JRE to here: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121`

This is whay I got in the cmd propmpt when checking the JRE version:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Do I need to download another version and put it in another location, such as `C:\Program Files(x86)` and then reinstall GeoServer? A tutorial I'm following says the destination folder will be in Program Files(x86)

Comment: what error you are getting when you try to access geoserver. Just for your information ,the latest version of Geoserver is 2.11.2.Why are you using older version?

Comment: I'm getting error 404 not found for localhost:8080/geoserver/web. I'm using the older version because I'm assuming it is more stable.